# C# SerialPort - RS485 How to receive all data in one part

Tags: c#, serial-port, rs485

I have a device that communicates through RS485 and I need to make a loopback in C# that receives my data and send them back. First byte contains information about the length of the coming data. Sometimes, it occurs that C# fire an event in several parts. I would need that I received them only in one part to I can send back in one go.

```
var buffer = new byte[1000];
port = new SerialPort(ConfigParams.PORT, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);                
port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
port.RtsEnable = true;
port.DtrEnable = true;                
port.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{  
  var length = port.ReadByte();                    
  Thread.Sleep(10);
  var bytes = port.Read(buffer, 1, length);
  buffer[0] = (byte)length;
  port.Write(buffer, 0, length + 1);
  mainForm.Log("Port (" + (length + 1).ToString() +"): " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length + 1)+"\n");
  mainForm.Log("Data was sended.\n");                    
};
```

In first step, I read first byte to get number of coming bytes. Then, I read the rest of the bytes. If I don't insert there the line Thread.Sleep(10), Event DataReceived will fire in several parts sometimes. With Thread.Sleep(10) it works correctly every time.

Do you know why it happens? I would expect that if I say I want to read 40 bytes, SerialPort will try to receive all those 40 bytes or occur an exception. I tried to change the property ReadTimeout but no change.

Comment: Do not use handshaking it is archaic and does not work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you call `SerialPort.Read()` it will wait for at least one byte in the buffer and then it will return all the bytes that it has, up to a maximum of the specified length.

**That means that it is possible for it to return less than the amount asked for.**

To circumvent this issue, you can write code similar to this (the important bit is in the `private blockingRead()` method):

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to read <paramref name="count"/> bytes into <paramref name="buffer"/> starting at offset <paramref name="offset"/>.
/// If any individual port read times out, a <see cref="TimeoutException"/> will be thrown.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="buffer">The byte array to write the input to. </param>
/// <param name="offset">The offset in buffer at which to write the bytes. </param>
/// <param name="count">The number of bytes to read from the port.</param>
/// <param name="timeoutMilliseconds">
/// The timeout for each individual port read (several port reads may be issued to fulfil the total number of bytes required).
/// If this is -2 (the default) the current <see cref="ReadTimeout"/> value is used.
/// If this is -1 or <see cref="SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout"/>, an infinite timeout is used.
/// </param>
/// <exception cref="TimeoutException">Thrown if any individual port read times out.</exception>

public void BlockingRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, int timeoutMilliseconds = SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault)
{
    if (timeoutMilliseconds < SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeoutMilliseconds),timeoutMilliseconds, $"{nameof(timeoutMilliseconds)} cannot be less than {SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault}." );

    int timeoutToRestore = setTimeoutAndReturnOriginal(timeoutMilliseconds);

    try
    {
        blockingRead(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    finally
    {
        if (timeoutToRestore != SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault)
            this.ReadTimeout = timeoutToRestore;
    }
}

private void blockingRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    while (count > 0)
    {
        // SerialPort.Read() blocks until at least one byte has been read, or SerialPort.ReadTimeout milliseconds
        // have elapsed. If a timeout occurs a TimeoutException will be thrown.
        // Because SerialPort.Read() blocks until some data is available this is not a busy loop,
        // and we do NOT need to issue any calls to Thread.Sleep().

        int bytesRead = _serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        offset += bytesRead;
        count -= bytesRead;
    }
}

private int setTimeoutAndReturnOriginal(int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    int originalTimeout = this.ReadTimeout;

    if ((timeoutMilliseconds != SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault) && (originalTimeout != timeoutMilliseconds))
    {
        this.ReadTimeout = timeoutMilliseconds;
        return originalTimeout;
    }

    return SerialComPortTimeout.UseDefault;
}
```

Be aware that the .Net implementation of `SerialPort` is flakey - see [this article](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) for details.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try it. Yes, I have already read that article, I usually use the method that was mentioned in the article. But for an easier demonstration was better use the code with DataReceived.